# Collision detection with KeyListener and scrolling background

Tags: java, collision-detection, keylistener

Im having a very strange problem with my code. Im making a little game for fun, but iv run into a problem with collisions. The really strange part is, the collisions are being detected, yet nothing is happening. Here is the code:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        int x = player.getCurX();
        int y = player.getCurY();

        for(int col = 0; col < X_AMOUNT; col++){
            for(int row = 0; row < Y_AMOUNT; row++){

                MazeBlock check = field[col][row];

                if(check.getState() == false){
                    int cX = check.getX()-(player.backX);
                    int cY = check.getY()-(player.backY);

                    if((y <= cY+BLOCK_SIZE && y >= cY) || (y+PLAYER_WIDTH >= cY && y+PLAYER_WIDTH <= cY+BLOCK_SIZE)){ // if on same y axis
                        if(x+PLAYER_WIDTH >= cX && x+PLAYER_WIDTH <= cX+BLOCK_SIZE){ // if coming from left
                            System.out.println("is coming from left");
                            player.setVelX(0);
                        } else {
                            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT|| key == KeyEvent.VK_D)
                                player.setVelX(1);
                        }

                        if(x <= cX+BLOCK_SIZE && x >= cX){ //if coming from right
                            System.out.println("is coming from right");
                            player.setVelX(0);
                        } else {
                            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || key == KeyEvent.VK_A)
                                player.setVelX(-1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP || key == KeyEvent.VK_W)
            player.setVelY(-1);
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || key == KeyEvent.VK_S)
            player.setVelY(1);
    }
```

Im going to explain all of this, because it is a lot to look at. 
-Variables x and y are the positions of the player.
-cX and cY are the positions of the block under it.
-player.setVelX sets the movement on the X plane. It is added to the current location of the player in order to move the player.
-the println statements show you what side the playing if coming to the block from.
-check.getState checks if the block that is being checked is a wall block

So whenever I touch a wall block, I get the correct message in the console, yet I'm still able to move around into the block. Does anybody have any ideas on how to fix it, or is it a lost cause?

Comment: `yet nothing is happening` Can you explain what you expect to happen?

Comment: I expected the player to stop on the edge of the wall block, where the coordinates have overlapped

Comment: Consider posting an [mcve]...it is unclear from the posted code what may be going on (which usually causes folks to guess)

Comment: `y <= cY && y >= cY+BLOCK_SIZE` unless `BLOCK_SIZE` is negative, this can't be true, can it?

Comment: oh, you're right. Thats very odd, because the println statements are still going off. Ill revise this right away and make edits.